# How do I make this run solely in the Console window? or can I make the Frame window hidden but still functional?

Tags: java, graphics, console, mouseevent, frame

If you're not familiar with HoltSoft's Ready To Program, and the console class within it, this is not a question you can answer.

Please don't suggest using anything from javax.swing, or anything that would make this an applet. I'm not supposed to use those.

```
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.*;
import hsa.*;

public class MouseTest extends Frame
{
    int startX, startY, endX, endY;
    Console c = new Console ();
    public MouseTest ()
    {
        super ();

        MouseListener start = new MouseListener ()
        {
        public void mouseClicked (MouseEvent e)
        {
        }

            public void mouseEntered (MouseEvent e)
            {
            }

            public void mouseExited (MouseEvent e)
            {
            }

            public void mousePressed (MouseEvent e)
            {
                startX = endX = e.getX ();
                startY = endY = e.getY ();
                repaint ();
            }

            public void mouseReleased (MouseEvent e)
            {
            }
        }
        ;
        addMouseListener (start);

        MouseMotionListener end = new MouseMotionListener ()
        {
            public void mouseDragged (MouseEvent e)
            {
                endX = e.getX ();
                endY = e.getY ();
                repaint ();
            }

            public void mouseMoved (MouseEvent e)
            {
            }
        }
        ;
        addMouseMotionListener (end);

    }


    public void paint (Graphics g)
    {
        super.paint (g);
        c.clear ();
        c.setColor (Color.black);
        c.drawLine (startX, startY, endX, endY);
    }


    public static void main (String args[])
    {
        Frame frame = new MouseTest ();
        frame.setLocation (950, 100);
        frame.setSize (400, 400);
        frame.show ();
    }
}
```

Okay so what this does is this:
 - opens up a Frame window and Console window that overlap
 - when the user clicks and drags on the Frame window, a line appears in the same spot on the console window

I tried hiding the Frame window to make it appear as if they user is drawing directly on the Console window, but that just seemed to disable the frame window.

Is there a way to make the Frame window invisible but active?
If not, is there a way to take out the Frame window altogether and put everything on the Console window?

Yes, I am required to do it on Console (HoltSoft Console class in Ready to Program)

I can't use JFrame becuase that's in javax.swing, which I am not allowed to use.

Comment: Why would you use `Frame` but not the new version `JFrame`?

Comment: What is the end goal of all of this?

Comment: You are using the holsoft `Console` class, you might want to mention that. Not everyone is familiar with Ready to Program.